# Phonegap 1.3.0 in Eclipse 3.7 on windows

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, extjs

I followed their "how-to":
[Phonegap Start](http://phonegap.com/start/#android)
[Phonegap wiki](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494774/Getting%20started%20with%20Android%20PhoneGap%20in%20Eclipse)

I have succesfully installed the android sdk, but I can not install phonegap 1.3.0. I'm stuck at this step:

> Step 4. Build the Example PhoneGap App

4A.  Open a command window and change directory ('cd') to the 'phonegap-android' folder.  In Windows, use git bash as the command window.  In Mac OS, use Terminal.

4B.  Run the following command.  This will create a PhoneGap.jar file and create a basic Android Eclipse project in the output path that can then be opened in Eclipse.

NOTE: The droidgap script has been updated and now there are two methods to create the necessary files. The new script is significantly simpler to use than the old method. For those who prefer the old method, it is still available.

NEW METHOD:

4C. From the 'phonegap-android' folder, run 'ruby bin/droidgap create [path_of_application]'. For the example app, the command would be 'ruby bin/droidgap create example'. If the example folder does not exist inside 'phonegap-android', run 'ruby bin/droidgap gen' first.

These are the steps that I have took:

- I have downloaded the callback package from git (see wiki)
- I run git bash --> cd to the phonegap-android folder
- I run this command: 'ruby bin/droidgap gen'
- Then I get: No such file or directory -- bin/droidgap(loadError) and idd the file isnt there.

I can't find droidgrap, who has the anser for me....... The old method don't work either, because I need droidgap for that one 2.

In the end I want to develop a Sencha web app for my android device. What did I forget.... :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AppLaud Eclipse plugin documented on the PhoneGap wiki [here](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/34483744/PhoneGap-Eclipse-PlugIn-for-Android) eliminates the need for droidgap or any other configuration. Its wizard creates a fully configured PhoneGap for Android project.

(Note: I developed the AppLaud plugin)